# When I use include I must have preamble only in one file?

Tags: beamer, include

I have a question. I try to include from one .tex file to another
My first file

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamercovered{dynamic}
    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
}

\include{presentation1}
```

My second file

```
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{dynamic}
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multimedia}



\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

When I put \documentclass{beamer} in my second file

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{dynamic}
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multimedia}



\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

I have an errors one I run my first file (file with include) like
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.
Package pgfarrows Warning: This package is obsolete. pgf.sty will load arrow ma etc

So when I use include I must always delete preamble from a source file or do something else?

Comment: You only have to ensure the commands used in the included file are all defined by the preamble of the main file.

Comment: The class should be loaded only once.

Comment: `\include` acts as if contents of the entire included file appear at the include point.  If you want to include a file that has its own preamble, take a look at the subfiles package.

Comment: also are you sure you want `\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}` almost all editors will default to UTF-8 now. anyone copying your example from this site would need to change that as all text on this site is UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to delete the preamble in the included file, instead you can use the `subfiles` package to ignore the preamble.

This way you can include files which themselves have `\documentclass{}` etc, but you will need to also load all packages and other settings in your main file. They won't be inherited from the included file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
    
\subfile{document}
    
\end{document}
```